# How do you change the gravity scale - for one second - at the start of the game and then revert back?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gravity, flappy-bird-clone

I'm trying to reduce the gravity scale of my flappy bird game for approximately 1 second at start time. I want to give the player a little time cushion before he falls more quickly.

I originally put the function in the start method (does a timer work in a non-update function?) I then put it in the update function.

Regardless, the timer doesn't seem to trigger, and the gravityscale doesnt go to normal (1).

You'll also see my comment where I was trying to lerp the gravity scale instead. Is it possible to lerp a gravity scale?

```
void Update()
{
    Jump();
    Rotation();
    PlayerHalt();
}

private void PlayerHalt()
{
    float gravityTimer = 0f;
    gravityTimer += Time.deltaTime;

    if (gravityTimer <= 1)
    {
        rb.gravityScale = .2f;
        //rb.gravityScale = Mathf.Lerp(.2f, 1f, gravityTimer / 1f);
    }
    else
    {
        rb.gravityScale = 1f;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use `IEnumerator` that acts like a Timer, at the bottom of the code you will see a simple Gravity Tweener.

```cs
private IEnumerator TweenGravity(float target, float duration)
{
    var baseGravity = rigidbody2D.gravityScale;
    
    var progress = 0f;
    while (progress < 1f)
    {
        progress += Time.deltaTime/duration;

        rigidbody2D.gravityScale = Mathf.Lerp(baseGravity, target, progress);
        
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
    }
}
```

```cs
public Rigidbody2D rigidbody2D; // setup your rigidbody on inspector

private void Start() => StartCoroutine(TweenGravity(1f, 1f)); // how to call IEnumerator
```

---

### How To Reverting gravity?

You can use an `Action` to give a callback at the end of the timer for reverting or other command.

```cs
private IEnumerator TweenGravity(float target, float duration, Action OnFinish = null)
{
    ///....

    OnFinish?.Invoke(); // this will call after wait progress finish
}
```

```cs
private void Start() => StartCoroutine(TweenGravity(1f, 1f, () => Debug.Log("On Finish callback")));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method that uses a simple *time delay* mechanism by taking note of the start time and measuring the current elapsed interval.   You can see it in the `Delay` class below.

Apart from `Time` (which you could easily replace with `DateTime` or even `Environment.TickCount`) it's essentially technology-neutral.  No nasty Unity coroutines necessary (which if used incorrectly are akin to `Application.DoEvents()`).

`Delay` class:

```
public class Delay
{
    private float _lastInterval;

    /// <summary>
    /// The timeout in seconds
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="timeout"></param>
    private Delay(float timeout)
    {
        Timeout = timeout;
        _lastInterval = Time.time;
    }

    public float Timeout { get; }

    public bool IsTimedOut => Time.time > _lastInterval + Timeout;

    public void Reset()
    {
        _lastInterval = Time.time;
    }

    public static Delay StartNew(float delayInSeconds)
    {
        return new Delay(delayInSeconds);
    }
}
```

Because it uses Unity's `Time.time` member it can be safely used from both `Update` and `FixedUpdate`.

### Usage

```
private Delay _delay;
private RigidBody rb;

void Start()
{
    rb = ...
    rb.gravityScale = .2f; // reduce the gravity scale

    _delay = Delay.StartNew(1f); // One second
}


void Update()
{
    if (_delay.IsTimedOut)
    {
        rb.gravityScale = 1f;
    }

    .
    .
    .
}
```

### Render throttling / Emulate a periodic timer

It can also be used in scenarios that demand reoccurring opperations spaced by a given frequency.

e.g. I use it a-lot for throttling processing or updates for rendering where I don't want to update things every frame but maybe every 100 ms.  I can achieve this by setting a `Delay` whereby I update rendering to the screen/buffer/`RenderTexture`/`Texture2D` like so:

```
private void Update()
{
    if (!_delay.IsTimedOut)
    {
        // not yet time
        return;
    }

    // perform rendering here


    _delay.Reset();
}
```